# MySQL Workbench y María DB, Se esperaba una coma o un corchete de cierre

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mariadb

Cuando conecto el MySQL Workbench a una Base de Datos MariaDB, aparece el error:

Se esperaba una coma o un corchete de cierre. (near "VISIBLE" at position...

Saben qué puede ser?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Explica un poco mas tu problema. Cuando te conectas y haces que cosa? tenes algun error en algun otro lado? es una instalacion limpia o hiciste algo?

Answer (score 3):

Ya he dado con la respuesta, sucede que MySQL Workbench viene configurado para trabajar con la versión 8 de MySQL, por lo que debemos cambiarla para hacerlo compatible con MariaDB.

En [esta página](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/) encontré la referencia a la compatibilidad de versiones. Al saber cuál es la versión compatible, lo que queda es configurarlo en MySQL Workbench:

1. Ir a Edit
2. Luego preferences
3. En la ventana que se abre ir a Modeling
4. Luego elegir MySQL
5. En el campo "Default target MySQL version" cambiamos el valor que allí aparece por la compatible, en mi caso fue la 5.7

[image: Cambio de versión MySQL Workbench]

Con esto ya funcionará correctamente.

Espero que les sirva tanto como a mi esta información.